# Any simplification of $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{(N-k)^2}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, hypergeometric-function

I am trying to find a compact expression for $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{(N-k)^2}$, where $N > n \geq 0$. Maple simplifies it using hypergeometric functions, which is not very useful. Any idea whether this can be simplified ? and if yes, how ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+%28n+choose+k%29*%28-1%29%5Ek%2F%28N-k%29%5E2+from+0+to+n&dataset=) uses Gamma & digamma functions, if that's better. Your sum diverges if $N$ is an integer from $0$ to $n$ inclusive; if it's another integer, their formula would require limit-taking to use.

Answer (score 4):

In order to evaluate where $N\gt n$

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{(N-k)^2} {n\choose k}$$

we introduce the function

$$f(z) = \frac{n! (-1)^n}{(N-z)^2}
\prod_{q=0}^n \frac{1}{z-q}.$$

This has the property that with $0\le k\le n$

$$\;\underset{z=k}{\mathrm{res}}\; f(z)
= \frac{n! (-1)^n}{(N-k)^2}
\prod_{q=0}^{k-1} \frac{1}{k-q}
\prod_{q=k+1}^n \frac{1}{k-q}
\\ = \frac{n! (-1)^n}{(N-k)^2}
\frac{1}{k!} \frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}
\\ = \frac{(-1)^k}{(N-k)^2} {n\choose k}.$$

Now residues sum to zero and the residue at infinity is zero so we may
evaluate using minus the residue at $z=N$. We find

$$- n! (-1)^n
\left.\left[ \prod_{q=0}^n \frac{1}{z-q}
\right]'\right|_{z=N}
\\ = n! (-1)^n
\left. \prod_{q=0}^n \frac{1}{z-q} \sum_{q=0}^n \frac{1}{z-q}
\right|_{z=N}
\\ = n! (-1)^n
\prod_{q=0}^n \frac{1}{N-q} \sum_{q=0}^n \frac{1}{N-q}
\\ = n! (-1)^n
\frac{(N-n-1)!}{N!} (H_N - H_{N-n-1}).$$

This is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1} {N\choose n+1}^{-1}
(H_N - H_{N-n-1}).}$$

Here we can nicely observe the poles when $N\le n$ (inverse binomial coefficient).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's brilliant!

Comment: A nice variation on a familiar theme. :-) (+1)